# Printing the node title instead of the file name from a field

Tags: 9

I have a block view, which is an unformatted list which prints my content type. All content has a field_file which I access using `views-view--download--field-file.html.twig`.

This prints a file link with the filename, like normal.
But is it possible to replace for example `document.txt` with `Document node title`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it directly from your View configuration using the "Rewrite results" option from field configuration.

- Edit your View
- Under the fields section, add your *Content: title* field, chexk "Exclude from display" and uncheck "Link to the content".
- then, add your file field *Content: my_file_field*, choose the formatter "URL to file" and expand the Rewrite results section. Check *Override the output of this field with custom text* and use the textarea to write the replacement text. It accepts HTML and, most importantly, tokens (you can see the list of available tokens under the "Replacement patterns" section). In the end, something like `<a href="{{ field_my_file_field }}">{{ title }}</a>` would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks it works!